# How can I add a class to an existing li with classes already assigned to it?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, jquery

How can I add a class to an existing `li` with classes already assigned to it?

My current code is on
http://jsfiddle.net/GbPdV/

I'm wanting to add the class of "Open" to:

```
< li class="dropdown hover carticon cart" >
```

I'm thinking that this has to happen inside of: (not sure)

```
 if ( response.Status == "Success" )
       {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "dmiajax.aspx?request=FloatingCart&extra=" + rnd(),
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(response) {
                    var floatingCart = $("ul.dropdown-menu.topcart");

                    if (floatingCart.length == 0) {
                        floatingCart = $('<ul class="dropdown-menu topcartopen"></ul>').insertBefore(".pull-right");
                        floatingCart.hoverIntent({
                            over: function() {},
                            timeout: 200,
                            out: function() {
                                $(this).stop(true, true).filter(":visible").hide("drop", {
                                    direction: "down"
                                });
                            }
                        });

                    }
```

Comment: Narrow your fiddle down considerably, we don't need your entire project, just the relevant bits to make an example replicating the actual issue.

Comment: I have edited out the parts I think are irrelevant. 
http://jsfiddle.net/GbPdV/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use `.addClass`

```
floatingCart.addClass("Open");
```

[addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)

```
success: function(response) {
    var floatingCart = $("ul.dropdown-menu.topcart");
        //HERE
        floatingCart.addClass("Open");
    if (floatingCart.length == 0) {
        //OR HERE
        floatingCart = $('<ul class="dropdown-menu topcartopen"></ul>')
               .insertBefore(".pull-right")
               .addClass("Open");;
        floatingCart.hoverIntent({
            over: function() {},
            timeout: 200,
            out: function() {
            $(this).stop(true, true).filter(":visible").hide("drop", {
            direction: "down"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Going out on a limb...I'm guessing I didn't do this right, as it's not working. (According to Bootstrap, the "open" class should open the dropdown)
http://jsfiddle.net/YxnRE/

Comment: Your fiddle has syntax error, fiddle doesnt include jquery library or bootstrap library, you are testing `if ( response.Status == "Success" )` when there is no response object... please fix your fiddle.

Comment: you are also calling the addClass in the wrong place, where you have it floatingChart doesnt exist yet. editing answer to show where it should go.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YxnRE/1/

I've tried to include everything. This was plopped in my lap, honestly, by a company that had a Developer quit. They have a lot of proprietary code stuff mixed in everywhere.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work either. http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/

Supposed to fire when you click "Add to cart" and apply the open state to the floating cart drop-down.